# Access extensions in the chrome://extensions page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is my `mainfest.json`:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "all_frames": true,
    "css": [ "css/event.css" ],
    "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ],
    "run_at": "document_start"
}
```

but I cannot find content script in the `chrome://extensions/` page
help!!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't because it could introduce a security risk where people add an extension that doesn't being deleted.

Comment: Why do you need to access chrome://extensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it on your PC by enabling `chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls` and adding the necessary url, `chrome://extensions/`, into `"matches"` in manifest.json but such extension won't be possible to install on a normal browser due to an invalid scheme error.

To avoid the fatal error, don't use manifest.json to inject the content script/style, do it manually in the background or popup script via `chrome.tabs.insertCSS` or `chrome.tabs.executeScript`:

- `chrome://flags`: enable `Extensions on chrome:// URLs` flag
- manifest.json:

  ```
  "permissions": ["chrome://*/*", "tabs"],
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  ```
- background.js:

  ```
  var chromeURLstylable;
  chrome.permissions.contains({origins: ["chrome://*/*"], permissions: ["tabs"]}, function(state) {
      chromeURLstylable = state;
      console.log("chrome:// urls support", state);

      if (chromeURLstylable) {
          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
              if (info.status == "loading" && tab.url.indexOf("chrome://") == 0) {
                  chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
                      file: "style.css", 
                      runAt: "document_start",
                      allFrames: true
                  });
              }
          });
      }
  });
  ```

Beware of possible problems submitting such extension to the Chrome Webstore.

Comment: I got an error: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: Invalid value for origin pattern tabs: Missing scheme separator.`